# change url ajax get request

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have an ajax call get

```
$.get('http://tvc.loc/search?searchData='+searchVal, function(returnData) {}
```

but have my base url stored in a variable

```
var url = (location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + 
  (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/");
```

but now i wan't to do something like this

```
$.get('"+url/search?searchData='+searchVal, function(returnData) {}
```

but i don't know if this is possible but i can't seem to get it working

Comment: You already seem to know about string concatenation, you just have to do it right. Do the same as `'...searchData='+searchVal` at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `+` to concatenate:

```
$.get(url + '/search?searchData='+searchVal, function(returnData) {});
```

Comment: Agreed this is deffo the way to go  =)